# Can't seem to set a font size lower than 0.583em?

Tags: html, css

In some browsers I'm testing I can't seem to be able to set the body font size to less than .583em. Is there a limit or has anyone run into this? It's on purpose as part of a design program of showing effects of small fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers have a minimum font size, and will round any smaller text up to this minimum. The value of this minimum is usually user-configurable, and the defaults depend on the browser.

If the browser you're using has a minimum font size set, there is no way to override it. Sorry. You'll probably have to use an image instead.